# Ruby with csv.open how to add more rows?

Tags: ruby, csv

What I'm looking to do is take all my product ID's in my sampleid text doc and have my script rotate through each one creating the product URL with that ID. I also want to have the id and the full url output into a csv file but my code below seems to only produce the last id in my doc... I'm assuming that its not moving to the next row for on `each_line do`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# ProductID script
puts "Enter current token"
auth_token = gets.chomp
File.open("sampleid.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
productNumber = line
  restcall = "mywebsite.com&token=" + auth_token + "&something.com/" + productNumber + ""
require 'csv'
CSV.open("/Users/Documents/scripts/ruby/rb_output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Product ID", "Full Call"]
  csv << [productNumber, restcall]
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the file freshly for every line, which means you're re-writing the file for every iteration of .each_line. Try this:

```
require 'csv'

puts "Enter current token"
auth_token = gets.chomp
CSV.open("/Users/Documents/scripts/ruby/rb_output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    File.open("sampleid.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
        productNumber = line
        restcall = "mywebsite.com&token=" + auth_token + "&something.com/" + productNumber + ""

        csv << ["Product ID", "Full Call"]
        csv << [productNumber, restcall]
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot tomorrow and accept if it works!